# Problems with writing Transfer Functions as Rational Expressions in s

Tags: matlab, undefined-function

Why do I get the error:

> [Undefined function 'tf' for input arguments of type 'char'.]

when I'm trying to use `[s=tf('s');]`?

The code worked just fine before updating my license, so I'm wondering if I missed something in the update.

Comment: `tf` is part of the control systems toolbox, is it installed and licensed on the system you are using? What does `ver` output.

Comment: I have the 8.4.0.150421 (R2014b) version...

Comment: Calling `ver` you get more information than that.

Comment: not a lot more... 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MATLAB Version: 8.4.0.150421 (R2014b)
MATLAB License Number: XXXXX
Operating System: Microsoft Windows 10 Home Version 10.0 (Build 10586)
Java Version: Java 1.7.0_11-b21 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MATLAB                                                Version 8.4        (R2014b)
>>

Comment: `ver` lists all the installed toolboxes. In your case, it seems no addditional toolbox has been installed :(

Comment: Ah, well that explains it . . . reinstalling, here I come!

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the documentation, you see [at the top left that the function tf is part of the control systems toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/tf.html). The output of ver tells you that no toolboxes are installed or activated. If you previously had the toolbox present on the same system there is probably a license issue. Try deactivating / activating the license.